# Matching Comma Separated mysql tags to database values (WP - PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$tagList = get_the_tag_list('','---','');
$totaltags = explode('---',$tagList);
foreach ($alltags AS $eachtag)
{
  $thistag = GetBetween($eachtag,'/tag/','/');
  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE thetag = '$eachtag'"
  $result = mysql_query($SQL, $link) or die(mysql_error());  
  if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
  {
     echo $thistag;
  }
}
```

This is my working code.  It works, but I really don't like having the SQL command in the foreach.  I assumed it wouldn't be an issue since there's no more than 8 tags on any given page.  Is there a more efficient way to code this?  (i.e. optimize for 1 mysql command or have less code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is my working code. It works, but I really don't like having the SQL command in the foreach. I assumed it wouldn't be an issue since there's no more than 8 tags on any given page. Is there a more efficient way to code this? (i.e. optimize for 1 mysql command or have less code)

Quite simple really:

```
<?php
// build quotes around the tags, this specific syntax is PHP 5.3+
$alltags = array_map( $alltags, function( $value ) { 
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string( $value ) . "'";
});

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE thetag IN ( %s );';
$sql = sprintf( $query, implode( ', ', $alltags ) );
echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.